# How to parse date in the GWT from WCF

Tags: java, json, gwt, gxt

I execute the `rest` request to the `WCF application’s service`. The service returns the `JSON` serialized business object which has the date property. The date comes in the following format:

```
"\/Date(1263412800000+0400)\/"
```

When I deserialize the coming line is set in the property with type String. Then I transfer the string to the date type by means of the category in the following way:

```
public static Date parseDateFromJsonString(String value) {
    if(value == null) return null;

    long dateValue = Long.parseLong(value.replaceAll(".+\\(|(\\+|\\-|\\)).+", ""));

    return new Date(dateValue);
}
```

For example, the server forwards the next date “14.01.2010 00:00:00”. But after the conversion it looks like “13.01.2010 23:00:00”.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I'm in 'GMT +4:00' time zone, and I wanna the same time zone value to display in.

NB

The current problem rises not in all browsers. I'm using `GWT 2.6` and `GXT 3.1.0`.

Comment: It's unclear where you're seeing the value "13.01.2010 23:00:00". I suspect this is just a matter of something applying time zones, but it's not clear. It would be really helpful if you'd explain where you're seeing each value (and how).

Comment: I know that the database be value 14.01.2010 00:00:00. However, the interface is displayed 13.01.2010 23:00:00.

Comment: What time zone is the original value meant to be in, what time zone are you in, and what time zone do you want the value displayed in?

Comment: Computer and value are in the same time zone. The problem is that on the same machine, but in different browsers value is displayed differently. In one appears 14.01.2010 00:00:00 and the other 13.01.2010 23:00:00. I want displayed in all browsers, the value of which came from the server (14.01.2010 00:00:00).

Comment: I hadn't spotted the browser difference before - that's interesting. Please give more details - what values do you get in which browser. Also note that "GMT +4:00" isn't really a time zone, it's just an offset at one point in time - what country are you in? It's possible that one browser is using one time zone database, and another is using a different one. The value 1263412800000 corresponds to 13-01-2010T20:00:00Z, by the way - so I can confirm that the local value should be 14-01-2010T00:00:00 *if* the offset was actually 4 hours at that date.

Comment: The country is Russia. The offset is actually 4 hours. Values in different browsers:

Windows 7 OS:
Google Chrome, FF, Safari, Opera, IE 9: 14-01-2010 00:00:00 UTC+4
IE 10,11: 13-01-2010 23:00:00 UTC +3

Mac OS:
Safari, Google Chrome: 13-01-2010 23:00:00 UTC +3

But the interesting fact is that the same function of date transfer in GWT 2.5.1 and GXT 2.3.1 works well.

Comment: The offset from UTC is 4 hours *now*, but it wasn't back in January 2010, as far as I can tell. So UTC+3 is actually correct - that's according to the IANA database. Goodness knows what the difference in GWT/GXT has to do with this :(